# Insert paragraphs in text, except within code blocks

Tags: php, regex

I'm inserting HTML paragraphs (`<p></p>`) into a piece of text, like this:

```
$text = '<p>' . preg_replace("/(\n|\r|\r\n)+/i", "</p><p>", $text) . '</p>' ;
```

Which seems to work well, except I don't want any paragraphs within `<code></code>` blocks since content within those blocks are pre-formatted (using a `white-space:pre;` style).

I'm not sure how best to handle this. I've tried to remove any such tags after the above line of code, but that's causing me some trouble and I figure it would be much better not to insert them in the first place.

Is it possible and/or practical to make the exclusion in the regex above? If not, what else?

Thanks

Edit: Came up with this code based on Nameless' answer below. It appears to work.

```
$chunks = preg_split("/(<code>.*?<\/code>)/is", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE) ;
$text = '' ;
foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
    if (preg_match("/^<code>/i", $chunk)) {
        $text .= $chunk ;
    } else {
        $text .= '<p>' . preg_replace("/(\n|\r)+/i", "</p><p>", $chunk) . '</p>' ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. This text "Line one\n\n\rLine two\r\nLine three\nLine four" would become "<p>Line one</p><p>Line two</p><p>Line three</p><p>Line four</p>". And I know CSS is for styling, but the HTML still tells CSS where to apply those styles.

Comment: You want to use an HTML toolkit for this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is possible with PCRE regex engine. Yet, highly irrational and resourse-heavy.

```
$text = '<p>' . preg_replace("/(\n|\r|\r\n)+(?!(.(?!<code>))*<\/code>)|(\n|\r|\r\n)+(?=<code>)/is", "</p><p>", $text) . '</p>' ;
```

Using DOM is probably the best solution, if you can spend some additional RAM on this operation. 
If not, you could split your string beforehand in chunks of `<code>` ... `</code>` and everything else, than use your regex on chunks not in `<code>`, than glue it back into string.

Comment: Thanks. The idea of splitting it up seems to be a good one. I edited in my solution based on that suggestion. It seems to work. I don't know if it's the most efficient way, maybe I'll look into DOM sometime.

Answer (score -1):

Never ever ever ever ever ever try to parse HTML with regex.

Use for example PHP's DOM: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

:)

Comment: Is that part of the standard installation of PHP, or something I need to install separately? If the latter, I may not have access to it (could check, of course).

Comment: @MCXXII: The `libxml` needs to be installed. Although it is installed by default I think. You can check your installed extensions by doing: `phpinfo();`

Comment: It's installed. I may look into it at some point. Thanks for the link.